# How to create a column with number of elements in list after applying splitlines() to another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, split

I have a dataframe:

```
col1
upload main/\then delete/\
for once
upload main/\then delete/\copy/\
```

I want to create new column with number of elements after applying splitlines() function to this column. But when I try this `df['col2'] = df['col1'].splitlines().str.len()` It says AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

How to do it?

desired result:

```
col1                                 col2
upload main/\then delete/\             2
for once                               1
upload main/\then delete/\copy/\       3
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, this would be the solution:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split('/\')))
```

Inside the quotes, you need to specify what you're splitting it with and will make a list, for example:

**upload main/\then delete/\ will be converted to ['upload main','then delete']**

and len() will basically return the length of the list formed.